# Is there a way to multiply values based on this pattern in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have jquery written for an ecommerce site, that adds a value to a field based on the quantity. It currently is set up to go up to 100 quantity, and I'm now looking at expanding the pattern to 1500. The code is along these lines:

```
 if ($("#quantity").val() >= 10 && ($("#quantity").val() <= 24)) {      
     $('#fieldVal').val('2');
 }
 else if ($("#quantity").val() >= 25 && ($("#quantity").val() <= 49)) {     
     $('#fieldVal').val('3');
 }
 else if ($("#quantity").val() >= 50 && ($("#quantity").val() <= 100)) {        
     $('#fieldVal').val('4');
 }
```

and so on. I could continue this pattern all the way up to 1500, but it would be nice if there's some way to shortcut it.

If the quantity is over 100, I want to use the value 4 and add in any other values based on quantity. 
If the quantity is 125, it should take the values 4 and 3 and add them together. If the quantity is 200, the value should be 8.

Comment: I don't see any multiplication being attempted here.

Comment: Correct, I'm looking to multiply these values to continue the pattern, instead of spelling each section out.

Comment: It isn't clear what that means *mathematically*, much less how to implement it in JavaScript.